# Get audit log data for specified period of time using office management api

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer, azureadapps

I am trying to obtain audit log from sharepoint online using Office management api.

When I use `https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/tenant-id/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint` as a Api url I am getting data of previous 24 hours but what I wanted data according to input date.

So I tried this url: `https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/tenant-id/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint&startTime=2019-02-26&endTime=2019-03-03`. I am getting

> 400 Bad Request" Error

What should be Request Url in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works!

Date should be in "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ" format

https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/tenant-id/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint&startTime=2019-02-26T00:00:00.000Z&endTime=2019-03-0318:29:59.999Z

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong date format. It should be in this format which is more url friendly.

YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Tried this, not working still same Error